# How to add a column showing if a user follows another user?

Tags: sql

I have a USER table which has the `userId` and the `name` of a user.

```
USER
_____________
userId | name
```

I also have a `Followers` table. Both columns are foreign keys of `userId`  of the USER table above. It shows that `userId` follows `other_userId`.

```
FOLLOWER
_____________________
userId | other_userId
```

Question:  How do i write a SQL statement that shows the following result?

```
EXPECTED QUERY RESULT
___________________________
userId | name | is_followed
```

It shows all users on the USER table with their id and name.
But, it also shows a 3rd boolean column `is_followed` that shows if the specific userId `123` follows the user on that row or not.

What I have tried...

```sql
select
    id,
    name
from account a
left join (
  -- i tried a  bunch of things here till my head hurt..
) f on f.userId = id
```

Comment: MySql or Postgresql - which is it?

Comment: I originally had it as a postgresql question, but I do not mind a response in mysql either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this ->

```sql
select
    id,
    name,
    bool_and(f.other_userId is not null)    
from user
left join (
    select 
        userId,
        other_userId
    from followers
    where userId = '123'
    group by userId, other_userId
) f on f.other_userId = id
group by id
```

This answer shows you all users, and if they follow user id `123` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Revised: To provide actual follower's id instead of Boolean.

```
with users (user_id, name) as 
     ( values (1,'user 1')
            , (2,'user 2')
            , (3,'user 3')
     ) 
     
   , followers ( user_id, other_userid) as 
     (values (1,2)
           , (3,1)
           , (1,3) 
     )
-- your query beging here 
select u.user_id
     , u.name
     , f.other_userid  is_followed
  from users u
   join followers f 
     on (  f.user_id = u.user_id)  
 order by u.user_id, f.other_userid;
```

---

Assuming Postgres, I do not know MySQL.  
A couple ways come quickly to mind. Basically what you are looking for is the existence of any row in the `followers` table with the same `userid` as the target (current) row of `user` table. Perhaps the easiest is just *ask* if that [exists](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)

```
with users (user_id, name) as 
     ( values (1,'user 1')
            , (2,'user 2')
            , (3,'user 3')
     ) 
     
   , followers ( user_id, other_userid) as 
     (values (1,2)
           , (3,1)
           , (1,3) 
     )
-- your query begins here 
select u.user_id
     , u.name
     , exists(select null 
                from followers f 
               where f.user_id = u.user_id
              ) is_followed 
  from users u 
 order by u.user_id;
```

You can get the same with the join you attempted, *although I do not understand why you user the `account` table, unless what you are asking in not the complete issue*, the trick being to look for Null/Not Null column from `followers`.

```
with users (user_id, name) as 
     ( values (1,'user 1')
            , (2,'user 2')
            , (3,'user 3')
     ) 
     
   , followers ( user_id, other_userid) as 
     (values (1,2)
           , (3,1)
           , (1,3) 
     )
-- your query begins here 
select distinct on (u.user_id) u.user_id
     , u.name
     , f.user_id is not null is_followed
  from users u
  left join followers f 
    on (  f.user_id = u.user_id) 
 order by u.user_id;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a74eba1162fc6d918720d3d470c1f0b3). In both cases the `with` clause is used just to supply data.  

I caution against `user` as a table name. It is a reserved word for both Postgres and SQL Standard. While it would be accepted at best it leads to confusion. Further what happens when the predefined/reserved meaning is enforced?

Comment: the part  i do not understand in the example you gave is the is_followed column. What exactly does it show?  It was supposed to be if a user with a specific id of `123` follows the users or not.

Comment: I tend to not use *as* when setting an alias.  I guess that is unfortunate. That is the only thing the `is_followed` column actually does. It gives the the result column the name you requested. Could have been `select ...  ) AS is_followed`

Comment: What i mean is the example shows 3 results. lets take row#1. It says user with id #1 is followed.  Is followed by who? by user with id #`123`?

Comment: That however is not what you asked. Rather  what you asked cannot be provided "*3rd boolean column is_followed that shows if the specific userId*. A boolean can only provide True or False (well also Null). But see the revised answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly a generic ansi-sql query would be

```
select u.UserId, u.name, 
  case when exists (
    select * from follower f
      where f.other_userId = u.userId
  ) then 1 else 0 end is_followed
from user u;
```

Also note from your description it should be correlating on *other_userid* otherwise you are showing the user *follows* not *is followed*.